# Getting ERROR as elements in attribute table after doing query in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, query

I was looking at an .osm file in QGIS using the OSM plugin; I was specifically looking at a country's lines layer. When I checked the attribute table just after opening the .osm, everything looked okay. After I did an advanced search using the search query builder, the system was able to highlight all matches. Good. But, when I reordered the entire table by moving all selections to the top of the table, most table elements were converted to 'ERROR' (from their original values).

Has anyone here encountered something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this "Error" if the dataset is updated while the attribute table is open.

The query dataset is smaller than before, but the attribute table does not get adjusted. Close and reopen it and the ERRORs will have gone.

This happens also if you delete elements in the attribute table, and click on `Save`. The number of records in the table stays the same, and the unused rows are filled with ERRORs.